# Can't run a HbaseTemplate demo

Tags: hbase, spring-data-hadoop

I am running HDP2.2 with Hbase 0.98.4.2.2.0.0 and HDFS 2.6.0.2.2.0.0, so I add the 2.1.2.RELEASE version of spring-data-hadoop to my maven pom file, but failed to complie because of "The type org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files", so should I add hbase-client to pom file?

Comment: I thought spring-data-hadoop should has hbase-client as it's dependency, but I found it does not, so I add the 0.98.4-hadoop2 version of hbase-client manually, then the program can compile, but failed with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$DeprecationDelta.

Comment: I should add hadoop-commons to pom.xml too.